# 100's of 1000's of report server jobs added - how to kill all?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs

A colleague wanted to run about 70 SSRS reports using the `EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData='E3843E8F-632E-4F2F-BE7C-63D4CF10F2ED'` command. (Changing `@EventData`)

Unfortunately he ran a cursor to loop through a list of them, but it seems to have just ran the first one around 500,000 times before it was cancelled. This seems to have added all of these to a queue of some sort that is constantly working them.

We have tried killing each process, restarting the ReportServer service, restarting the entire server, but each time new jobs continue to be created. How do I clear whatever queue these are sitting in?

This is kind of urgent, what do we need to do?

I am searching through the `ReportServer` database for a table to remove the rows from, the ones that stand out are `Notifications` and `ExecutionLogStorage` as these have enough data in them, but the likes of `RunningJobs` is empty.

Comment: Do you see a large number of records in `select count(*) from msdb.dbo.sysjobs`?

Comment: There was not a lot in `sysjobs`. It seemed to run only 10 at a time, so `sysjobs` was always relatively small.

Comment: I saw you resolved the issue. I asked because each call to `addevent` will create a new sql agent job with GUID in the name.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't directly create a new sql agent job, it put them in a queue to be created. Obviously if there are a small number added then it will get directly added to `sysjobs` but with over 300k (when I caught it) they were only queued.

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong in my assumption that `Notifications` was not the table to be looking in. It was exactly the right one. Deleting all where the ReportID matched the one we were looking at fixed the problem.

```
DELETE FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Notifications] WHERE ReportID = '4837A901-7188-4FCB-B86A-7974D35D9F56'
```